# SQL Column does not include value

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I'd like to ask you to help me with a problem

I currently have SQL tables `PRODUCT` and `PRODUCT_PARAMETER`.

`PRODUCT` has one interesting field: `PRODUCT_ID` (and bunch of others, not important).

`PRODUCT_PARAMETER` is linked to `PRODUCT` on `PRODUCT_ID` and has columns `KEY` and `VALUE`.

I need to find out all products that have no `PRODUCT_PARAMETER` with key "cost" or they have the parameter but the value is `NULL`. There can be `PRODUCT_PARAMETER` with different key

Also, due to restrictions of the system I am using it with, I cannot change structure of the DB and must do it within one SQL command,the latter is probably causing me most pain, because I am fairly confident with being able to pull either half of what I need from DB

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT MINUS 
SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT_PARAMETER WHERE KEY LIKE 'cost';
```

pulling out products that have not the parameter and

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID FROM PRODUCT_PARAMETER WHERE KEY LIKE 'cost' AND VALUE IS NULL
```

for pulling out products with NULL values at existing key.

At the top level, I need to put both of these results into single sys_refcursor which is defined by blueprint like this

```
FUNCTION VALIDATION_FCTN RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    v_rc sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN v_rc FOR #fillSelectStatementHere;
    RETURN v_rc;
END;
```

Which I can slightly modify as long as it returns all values in single refcursor, in case merging cursors is better than a `SELECT` statement. Although I am very fresh to SQL programming and never saw `PLSQL` before, so I would prefer the `SELECT` solution, if possible.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why `LIKE` without any wild-cards? (I'd probably use `=` instead.)

Comment: @jarlh well it is just a custom here. All the other tests are written with LIKE when there are strings concerned, wild cards or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to get rid of products which have not null cost:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID 
  FROM PRODUCT 
MINUS 
SELECT PRODUCT_ID 
  FROM PRODUCT_PARAMETER  
  WHERE KEY = 'cost' AND VALUE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I feel so so silly right now O.o I wonder why this did not occur to me when I was writing this down

Answer (score 0):

Alternative, which may generate a better plan:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID
FROM PRODUCT P
LEFT OUTER JOIN PRODUCT_PARAMETER PP
    ON PP.PRODUCT_ID = P.PRODUCT_ID
    AND PP.KEY = 'cost'
WHERE PP.VALUE IS NULL
```

`PP.VALUE` will be null when no product parameter with key `'cost'` exists and when the paremeter does exist, but the value is null.

Assumes:

- `PRODUCT (PRODUCT_ID)` is unique.
- `PRODUCT_PARAMETER (PRODUCT_ID, KEY)` is unique.